# Remove input when value is not set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I got a list where PHP creates an `<input type="text" readonly value="' . $row[$item] . '">';` from mySQL. Sometimes a field in the database table is empty, so the input would just look like this: `<input type="text" readonly value>';` So there *is* a value tag, but there isn't any value.
What I try to do is just to remove the empty inputs.
I tried using this code:

```
function clearEmpty(){
  var input = $('.plannerlist input').val();
  if(input < 0){
    $('.plannerlist input').remove();
  }    
}
```

`.plannerlist` is the following list:

```
<ul class="plannerlist" id="plannerlist1">
  <input type="text" readonly value="Some value here">
  <input type="text" readonly value>
  <input type="text" readonly value="or no value like above">
  <input type="text" readonly value>
</ul>
```

The function I wrote above is not working at all. No input gets removed, no console error, nothing...
What could be the problem?

That's my PHP (i know it's a mess, but it works ;) ):

```
<?php
$host    = "********";
$user    = "********";
$pass    = "********";
$db_name = "********";

//create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

//test if connection failed
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
die("connection failed: "
. mysqli_connect_error()
. " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
. ")");
}
echo '<div id="content">
<form action="save.php" method="post">
<section class="tabcontent">
<ul class="plannerlist" id="plannerlist1">';
//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT FR_PM FROM anmeldungen");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
foreach ($all_property as $item) {
echo '<input type="text" readonly value="' . $row[$item] . '">'; //get items using property value
}
}
echo '</ul>

</section>
<section class="tabcontent">
<ul class="plannerlist" id="plannerlist2">';
//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT SA_AM FROM anmeldungen");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
foreach ($all_property as $item) {
echo '<input type="text" readonly value="' . $row[$item] . '">'; //get items using property value
}
}
echo '</ul>
</section>
<section class="tabcontent">
<ul class="plannerlist" id="plannerlist3">';
//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT SA_PM FROM anmeldungen");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
foreach ($all_property as $item) {
echo '<input type="text" readonly value="' . $row[$item] . '">'; //get items using property value
}
}
echo '</ul>
</section>
<section class="tabcontent">
<ul class="plannerlist" id="plannerlist4">';
//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT SO_AM FROM anmeldungen");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
foreach ($all_property as $item) {
echo '<input type="text" readonly value="' . $row[$item] . '">'; //get items using property value
}
}
echo '</ul>
</section>
<section class="tabcontent">
<ul class="plannerlist" id="plannerlist5">';
//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT SO_PM FROM anmeldungen");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
foreach ($all_property as $item) {
echo '<input type="text" readonly value="' . $row[$item] . '">'; //get items using property value
}
}
echo '</ul>
</section>
<section class="tabcontent">
<ul class="plannerlist" id="plannerlist6">';
//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT MO_AM FROM anmeldungen");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
foreach ($all_property as $item) {
echo '<input type="text" readonly value="' . $row[$item] . '">'; //get items using property value
}
}
echo '</ul>
</section>
<input name="plannersubmit" id="plannersubmit" type="submit">
</form>
</div>';

?>
```

Comment: `$('.plannerlist input') ` returns a list, you cannot just `.val()` a list. You have to fetch all items in your list.

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu Ah that's true...

Comment: WHAT is the actually purpose of your attempted solution? I feel like there is a better way of handling this than removing inputs with javascript. As your solution appears to be some sort of workaround for empty fields, please read http://xyproblem.info/ and then think about your question.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus I'm trying to help. But one might easier help you with a question addressing the problem, not your attempted solution. See, if you ask "How can i change the battery of my car" - everyone would try to explain. If at the end your battery wasn't the problem, but your fuel was empty it would have been better to ask: "My car doesn't start, how to solve this?" - But without knowing that your car just wont start, nobody would figure out the solution. (Blame me for this dumb example :P )

Comment: @TobiasGlaus can you just put condition in your php foreach just echo if the data is not empty? so in the front end all results will be not empty.

Comment: @dognose So if my questions title was: "Removing inputs with empty value doesn't work, how do I solve this?" it'd change anything? ;)

Comment: Halfway there :-) - Why are there empty inputs, how are you generating them, when should they be there and when not?

Comment: I mean as i understood you are generating inputs for every database column. Why isn't it possible to update "empty" fields, and why are you generating the inputs at all (See Gian Tomakins answer)

Comment: @dognose Okay I see ;) Gonna remember that when posting my next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//in your php foreach can you just do it like this?

```
foreach ($all_property as $item) {
 if($row[$item] != NULL || $row[$item] != '')
 {
   echo '<input type="text" readonly value="' . $row[$item] . '">'; 
 }
```

}

Comment: `&&` - it should be `and`. `($x != null || $x != '')` is always `true`, cause it can't be `NULL` and `''` at the same time, so one condition always matches. :-)

Comment: Thanks Gian ! Works perfectly. @dognose what do you mean with your comment? It works for me like that.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus The problem is hard to explain: PHP does some "Auto-Magic" rendering `''` and `null` equal, when only using `!=`. Thus, this works, even if it is not correct in terms of a boolean language. See this snippet: https://3v4l.org/Mre2U The case having strict-comparisions along with `AND` rather than non-strict comparisions with `OR` would be the correct solution. Just think about: You want to `hide` the element If it is NEITHER null NOR empty - thus you need to check 2 conditions, thus you need "AND". If PHP would not do it's "magic" this would display the content at any time, (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) See the example outlined as "OTHER-OR". No matter if `''` or `null` the content is displayed.

Comment: easier to understand example: https://3v4l.org/7ICIN (The code of this answer only works for php, cause it considers `''` to be equal to `null`, thus the condition can become `(false || false)` - which obviously can never ever happen in a boolean language - cause if it does not match the left side, it matches the right side - and vice versa.

Comment: @dognose what my condition did is just filtering if its empty dont display it if it has value display it. thats it. just keeping it simple.

Comment: you can even use this one if(!empty($row[$item])){ display stuff }

Comment: @GianTomakin empty is okay - just saying that your example is wrong boolean logic. It works in PHP cause `null==''`, but never the less it's wrong :-) Usually your code would display empty strings, cause when the first part is true, the second isn't even evaluated. So, empty string is different from null -> `true | whatever` -> display it. With `&&` you would logically cover both cases.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.plannerlist input')` returns an array of inputs.

You need to loop over it and find the elements where `val() == ''`.

```
var inputs = $('.plannerlist input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    if ($(input).val() == '') {
        $(input).remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That unfortunately doesn't work for me aswell :/

Comment: I've just noticed that. I've fixed it. Does it work now?

Comment: No, it doesn't :/ I have to define the variable inputs at the beginning right? (`var inputs = $('.plannerlist input').val();`)

Comment: Leave out the `.val()`.

Comment: Still wont work :/ You can check it out yourself at the website: http://lars-widmer.tk/sites/18/ at the bottom of the page, after sliding the slider. You can select some of the tabs and then content should show up (taken from my mySQL table)